# django image gives me an error "This field is required."

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

When I send an image to the bank to save, it always returns this message "This field is required." but I fill the field with an image but it always returns this error.

## Views

```
def criar (request): 
    form = forms_user() 

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms_user(request.POST, request.FILES )
               
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()      
            messages.add_message(request, constants.SUCCESS, 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso.')
            form_clean = forms_user()
            return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form_clean})    
            
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            messages.add_message(request, constants.ERROR, f'{form.errors}')
            return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form})
```

## Models

```
class items(models.Model):

    titulo:models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    descricao = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    usuario = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    Preco = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
    royalties = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', null=True, blank=True)
```

## Forms

```
class forms_user (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = items
        fields = '__all__'
```

## HTML

```
<form id="contact" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <fieldset>
                  
   <label for="file">Seu arquivo</label>
                    
    {% render_field form.image type="file" id="file" name="myfiles[]" %}                    
                  
   </fieldset>

</form>
```

Here in the forms I just put the form and the IMG field so it doesn't get too big but the other fields I put everything right.

Comment: Please share code instead of uploading images of code.

Comment: The problem is with `criar` view, you didn't make it correctly to process both POST and GET request.

Comment: What should I do to process correctly?

Comment: In the form you have an _all_ which corresponds to all the elements of the model. In the model you don't have any "file" field but a field called "image". Change the template by putting correctly the tags by "image" in the id of html.

Comment: Also, in your form you must specify that the "image" field is optional.
class forms_user (forms.ModelForm):
image = MyFormField(
        required=False,
    )
...

Answer (score 0):

At first there's a typo in model field `titulo` it should be `=` not `:`.

Secondly, you should always return an HttpResponseRedirect after dealing with `POST` data, the tip is not specific to Django, it's a good web practice in general, so use following view:

```py
def criar(request): 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': forms_user()})

    else:
        form = forms_user(request.POST, request.FILES )
               
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()      
            messages.add_message(request, constants.SUCCESS, 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso.')
            return redirect("success")   
            
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            messages.add_message(request, constants.ERROR, f'{form.errors}')
            return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': forms_user()})
```

If you have created modelform then render image field as below, and you can also remove the `action` attribute as Django by default takes current page route.

Html:

```html
<form id="contact" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <fieldset>
                  
   <label for="file">Seu arquivo</label>
                    
    {{form.image}}                                    
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns=[
    path("success/", views.success, name="success")
    ...
]
```

success.html:

```html
<body>
    <h1> The form has been successfully submitted </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by passing the fields to the FORM, I was getting all the MODELS fields with '__all__' and it was giving an error

Comment: @EulerBorgesdaMotta Glad to hear you solved the problem :)

Comment: class forms_user (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = items
        fields = ['titulo', 'descricao', 'Preco', 'royalties', 'image']

Comment: @EulerBorgesdaMotta Have you changed `:` to `=`? Did you try the view I suggested?

Comment: yes, but that wasn't the error, it was why I was getting all the fields from the models with '__all__'.

Comment: @EulerBorgesdaMotta But you haven't mentioned in the question, sorry I understood it incorrectly, you can suggest the edit to my answer.

Comment: I sent you the wrong models I had another model that was giving error. my fault in the end :(

Comment: @EulerBorgesdaMotta Ah, anyway edit my Answer with right answer worked for you, and also edit the question with right model.

Comment: There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.

Comment: Anyway, try later and told me :) @EulerBorgesdaMotta